# Simple Get request?

Tags: html

I am trying to make a simple get  style submission input box.  For example

I have little tags I hand out that have a code on them (7648hy)  you can go to the website and enter in the code. It takes you to a webpage of

http://www.mypage.com/7648hy.html

or the tag is
 5879JJI

input it in the text box on the main page and you get taken to

http://www.mypage.com/5879JJI

Simple easy?

Comment: What the Heck is a "simple get style submission input box" ?

Answer (score 0):

With plain HTML you can only use form with GET method and get something like
`mypage.com?page=jmjkl231`
otherwise, you need to use another language, best would be javascript.

```
<input type="text" id="id" onchange="myfunc();">
<script>
myfunc() {
   window.location=document.getElementById("id").value;
}
</script>
```

(Not sure, if exactly this will work, but you get the idea.)

EDIT:

If you need a submit button, simply add button to trigger the function:

```
<input type="text" id="id">
<button onclick="myfunc();">
<script>
myfunc() {
   window.location=document.getElementById("id").value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, well not sure to be honest. I have given that a try but not sure, if I put in a submit button for the action to be taken?   As example, with that code, it gives me the text box needed yes.  I then enter in a code like 986547  and then hit a submit button, that takes me to http://www.mywebsite.com/986547 .  How would I add a submit button to that script to get that to work?

Comment: Ok, I have tried that as well. But something is still not right as it still wont work. Here is what I tried.<input type="http://www.google.com" id="id">
<button onclick="myfunc();">
<script>
myfunc() {
   window.location=document.getElementById("id").value;
}
</script>
</button>